# correct format for date in PayPal API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I call the Sync API:

`url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2018-01-02&end_date=2018-02-02'`

and it returns the following error:

`{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","debug_id":"f1274e478292e","message":"Invalid request - see details.","details":[{"field":"start_date","value":"2018-01-02","location":"query","issue":"Invalid date passed"}]}`

What is the correct format for start_date?

Answer (score 4):

it should be in a following format:

`2018-02-01T00:00:00Z`

then it works ok.

Comment: Seems to be the case - I tried using +10:00 instead of Z and that resulted in an error.

Answer (score 0):

For people that want to use time zones other than UTC (especially with positive offset):

The `+` sign has a semantic meaning in the query string: It is used to represent a space. If you want an actual plus sign in your route, you have to use `%2B`, like the following for CET:

```
2023-10-01T00:00:00%2B01:00
```